# Magento admin: how to add a custom search form

Tags: ajax, magento, search, admin

I need to add a custom Ajax search form in Magento admin in "Customer Information" => "Orders". Form search by `id`, `sku`, and product names.

[image: here]

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO)! I edited the link you posted, so the image shows in the post. I also formatted `id`, and `sku`, it makes it show more. Lastly, I deleted the 'thanks', this is commonly used by first users, and makes the post look a little clunky. Have fun, and good day!

Comment: Please post what you have tried already.

Comment: I do not know where to start. :( I know how add sort to grid header, know how make Ajax request, Know how add/remove standart buttons like "search", "reste filter" etc. But don't know how add custom search form near/in filter-actions buttons :(

Answer (score 0):

OK I solved problem. 
Just create override of grid.phtml

**/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml**

Like this

**/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/myNamespace/myModule/widget/grid.phtml**

And add HTML After $this->getExportTypes()

```
<?php if($this->getExportTypes()): ?>
...(html)
<?php endif; ?>

<td class="fhrajaxsearch a-right filter">            
            <div class="field-50" style="display: inline-block;">
                <input type="text" name="fhr_id_sku_name" id="fhr_customer_orders_grid_filter_id_scu_name" value="" class="input-text">                
            </div>            
            <button id="fhr_search" title="Search" type="button" class="scalable task" onclick="customer_orders_gridJsObject.doFilter()" style="">
                <span>
                    <span>
                        <span>Search</span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </button>
        </td>
```